# What is the os.name system property value in Java on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL 2)

Tags: java, wsl-2

How does Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) look like from a Java application.
Specifically what are the values of `"os.name"` and `"os.version"` in the system properties?

Answer (score 0):

Here's using WSL 2 together with a Linux build of AdoptOpenJDK 8.

- "os.name" returns "Linux"
- "os.version" for me returns "5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2"
- "user.home" returns "/home/foo"